# Alternative proof of linearity of discrete expectation

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, alternative-proof, expected-value

I'm trying to prove linearity of expectation for discrete case, i.e. $$\sum \limits_i E\left[X_i\right] = E \left[\sum \limits_i X_i \right]$$

Firstly, I introduce the following notation: $p_{ij} = P(X_i = j)$

If $X_i$ doesn't take value $j$, then $p_{ij} = 0$.

Then:

$\sum \limits_i E\left[X_i\right] = \sum \limits_i \sum \limits_j j \cdot p_{ij} = \sum \limits_j j \cdot \sum \limits_i p_{ij} = \sum \limits_j j \cdot p_j = E\left[\sum \limits_i X_i \right]$

Is this correct?

Comment: There is no need to limit yourself to the discrete case. Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be integrable random variables, i.e. $\mathbb E[|X_i|]<\infty$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] &= \int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)\ \mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\Omega} X_i(\omega)\ \mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i],
\end{align}
by linearity of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: If you want to avoid the measure-theoretic definition of expectation, then write $$E[X_i] = \int_{\mathbb R} x\ \mathsf dF_i(x) $$ where $F_i$ is the distribution function of $X_i$ and the integral is interpreted as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral (to account for the $X_i$ possibly being discrete, continuous, or a mix).

Comment: No, this is not correct. Two last equalities are wrong.